# Query month in date custom field on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a query to get all posts that date custom field are before a month sended by URL var. Custom field saves data like YYYYMMDD (20150330). I want to get all post before this year/month (201503).

I try this but it doesn't works, because date_added content it isn't YYYYMM. It contains day too.

```
$year = $_GET['year'];
$month = $_GET['mes'];

$yearmonth = $month." ".$year;

$args = array (
        'post_type' => 'clients',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'post_title',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'client_type',
                'compare'   => '=',
                'value'     => 'Si',
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'date_added',
                'compare'   =>  '<=',
                'value'     => date("Ym", strtotime($yearmonth)),
            )
        ));

   $posts = get_posts($args);
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: If the date is stored in the database as an integer, then look where date less than `date("Ym00", strtotime($yearmonth))` (zeros for day) for everything before March-1 or if you wanted the month of march use `"Ym99"` to signify a date in march that is greater than the last day but still less than the following month. The date `20150301` as an integer translates to `20,150,301` (twenty million, one hundred fifty thousand, three hundred and one). No date will be below `201,503` so you need to add the day numbers to make them in the same scale.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn This seems like something that should be part of a potential answer.

Comment: @shawn Yes, it should. I started it smaller and kept adding to it. They tend to blow up like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date is stored in the database as an integer, then look where date less than `date("Ym00", strtotime($yearmonth))` (zeros for day) for everything before March-1 or if you wanted the month of march use `"Ym99"` to signify a date in march that is greater than the last day but still less than the following month. The date `20150301` as an integer translates to `20,150,301` (twenty million, one hundred fifty thousand, three hundred and one). No date will be below `201,503` so you need to add the day numbers to make them in the same scale.